# Referencing another function containing a 'this' reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, onload

A colleague of mine has written various Javsascript functions which show certain HTML elements dependent on the answers to various inputs. This is an example of one of the functions, which are all very similar.

```
function addSponsership(sponser) {
    if (sponser.value == "N") {
        document.getElementById('nameofperson').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('nameofpersonvalue').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('address').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('addressvalue').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('postcode').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('postcodevalue').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('telephone').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('telephonevalue').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('fax').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('faxvalue').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('emailaddress').style.display = "block";
    }

    if (sponser.value == "NH") {
        document.getElementById('nameofperson').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('nameofpersonvalue').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('address').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('th1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('th8').style.display = "table-row";
    }

    if (sponser.value == "Y") {
        document.getElementById('nameofperson').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('nameofpersonvalue').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('address').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The function is called from the HTML with an onclick event which looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="IPQ_FUND1" id="IPQ_FUND1" value="Y" checked="checked" onclick="addSponsership(this);"/>
```

I now want to call all of these functions using the onload event on the body element. However, I am unsure how to do this. Example:

```
function callAllOtherFunctions()
{
 addSponsership(sponser)
 addSponsership2(sponser)
 addSponsership3(sponser)
 etc...
}
```

The problem with this is that I can't find a way to refer to the specific elements whose values need to be checked. Ideally I need to find a solution to this without editing the original functions written by my colleague.

I tried to do it individually by creating another function that looked like this:

```
function addSponsershipLoad(inputID){
  sponser = document.getElementById(inputID);
   addSponsership(sponser);
    }
```

and editing the body tag to look like this:

```
<body onload="addSponserShipLoad('IPQ_FUND1');">
```

but despite the console not showing any errors, this didn't work.

So, I know I'm probably being quite thick and the solution will be simple, but please help if you can.

Comment: according to the posted code "addSponsership" doesn't have a case for 'IPQ_FUND1' just 'N', 'NH', and 'Y'.  this is likely the cause of failure.

Comment: I Think u dont need a seperate function to pass the sponsor object. you can do it like this , from body call this function on load `callAllOtherFunctions(objId)` then in callallotherfunctions just extract the object reference using the id . `function callAllOtherFunctions(objId)
{
   sponser = document.getElementById(objId);  
addSponsership(sponser)
 addSponsership2(sponser)
 addSponsership3(sponser)    }`

Comment: Are you sure you're passing an input, the code looks fine from what I can see. Maybe you can console.log some variables in addSponsershipLoad like `console.log(sponser); console.log(sponser.value)` and in addSponsership: `console.log(sponser); console.log(sponser.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put everything in variables:

```
addSponsership(document.getElementById('IPQ_FUND1'));
addSponsership2(document.getElementById('IPQ_FUND2'));
// ...
```

Comment: Since its mentioned that a single radio button's status/value is considered on body load ,we can extract the object with respect to the id only once and pass it to various function like addSponsership(),addSponsership2()...etc

Comment: Works perfectly. I knew it would be simple!

Answer (score 1):

In the onload-event, call a function that binds all handlers:

```
<body onload="setHandlers()">
```

In that function, set an onclick-handler for as many inputs as you need:

```
function setHandlers() {
    document.getElementById('IPQ_FUND1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        addSponsership(event.target);
    });
    document.getElementById('IPQ_FUND2')...
}
```

Comment: This sounds adventurous, and like it would be useful, but the answer above was a lot simpler. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like your solution should work as posted above. Below is a minimal proof-of-concept. Hard to tell from the question if you will be feeding the values of different elements to your colleague's functions, or if they will all key off of the same element. The "addSponserShipLoad" function below assumes the first case. If the second case is true, you'd just use the element id as a parameter to the function, and pass the returned element to all of the called functions.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mA4XM/)

HTML:

```
<body onload="addSponserShipLoad()">
<input type="radio" name="IPQ_FUND1" id="IPQ_FUND1" value="Y" checked="checked" onclick="addSponsership(this);"/>
<input type="text" name="nameofperson" id="nameofperson" value="A. Person" />
```

JS:

```
function addSponserShipLoad() {
    addSponsership(document.getElementById("IPQ_FUND1"));
}

function addSponsership(sponser) {
    if (sponser.value == "N") {
        document.getElementById('nameofperson').style.display="block";
    }
    if (sponser.value == "NH") 
    {
        document.getElementById('nameofperson').style.display="none";
    }
    if (sponser.value == "Y") {
         document.getElementById('nameofperson').style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Edit: Change the value of the "IPQ_FUND1" element to "N" in the fiddle to see what it's doing.